# d3 svg path attr d assignment fails in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, jupyter-notebook, directed-graph

In working on a directed graph visualization in d3 I followed [Martin Graham's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368214/mgraham)  jsfiddle [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/a5ua66zy/2/) to create bezier arcs for multiple links between two nodes. This worked a treat and I'm grateful for his guidance. The current state of development of my working example can be seen [here](http://neolography.com/staging/d3v5digraphTest.html). The d3 code is right in the HTML in `<script>` tags. The function for generating those arcs looks like this:

```
  function linkArc(d,i,lnks) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
    var qx = dy /  6 * d.linknum,
        qy = -dx / 6 * d.linknum;
    var qx1 = (d.source.x + (dx / 2)) + qx,
        qy1 = (d.source.y + (dy / 2)) + qy;

    return `M${d.source.x} ${d.source.y}
            C${d.source.x} ${d.source.y}, ${qx1} ${qy1}, ${d.target.x} ${d.target.y}`;
  };
```

And it is called from within the `drawGraph` function like this:

```
simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link.attr("d", linkArc);
    ...etc...
```

Well and good, this works. But what I'm aiming at is deploying this visualization in the context of a Jupyter Notebook, and in that context when d3 tries to render those links, I get a javascript error on each `tick()` saying `Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN NaN\n        …".`

`linkArc()` does return a string, but I'm hoping someone wiser in the ways of Jupyter and/or d3 can explain to me why that string works in one context, but not the other.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this puzzle is almost too embarrassing to recount, but in the unlikely event that anyone was mildly curious, I finally realized that the x and y coordinates of the nodes were not being calculated because they depend on `width` and `height` of the svg element, and those variables were declared outside the `drawGraph` function that I had moved, unrevised, into the javascript module imported by the Notebook via `require.js`.

This was due, in part, to my complete unfamiliarity with how `require.js` works, and to the fact that the error message told me only about the consequence of my oversight rather than its cause. Let this be a lesson to me: variables have SCOPE. And part of the whole point of javascript modules is to control and confine scope.